# How to get a field's teaser with php?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, teaser

Is there a way to get a field's teaser value with php? I can get the fields value with some php like this..

```
<?php print $node->field_country[0]['value'] ?>
```

I tried this..

```
<?php print $node->field_country[0]['teaser'] ?>
```

But that does not work. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
<?php print $node->field_country['und'][0]['value'] ?>
```

This could work.

If it didn't, use

```
<?php print_r($node->field_country); ?>
```

to go through the properties of the field.

Answer (score 1):

Fields don't have "teaser" and "full" values. Only nodes have teser and full views.

To see the full contents of a field array in Drupal 6, install the Devel module and use:

```
<?php dpm($node->field_country); ?>
```

Note that the previous suggestions:

```
<?php print $node->field_country['und'][0]['value'] ?>
```

relates to the structure of fields in Drupal 7.